# Is there any appropriate way to share humorous sermons?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I was just reading the following from Spurgeon's [The Sympathy of the Two Worlds](http://www.spurgeon.org/sermons/0203.htm)

(minor paragraph splitting to simply reading)

> But I want you just to read the text again, while I dwell upon another thought. "There is joy in the presence of the angels of God over one sinner that repenteth." Now, why do they not save their joy till that sinner dies and goes to heaven? Why do they rejoice over him when he repents? My Arminian friend, I think, ought to go to heaven, to set them right upon this matter. According to his theory, it must be very wrong of them, because they rejoice prematurely. According to the Arminian doctrine a man may repent, and yet he may be lost, he may have grace to repent and believe, and yet he may fall from grace and be a castaway. Now, angels, don't be too fast. Perhaps you may have to repent of this one day, if the Arminian doctrine be true, I would advise you to save your song for greater joys. Why, angels, perhaps the men that you are singing over to-day, you will have to mourn over to-morrow.
>
> I am quite sure that Arminius never taught his doctrine in heaven. I do not know whether he is there—I hope he is, but he is no longer an Arminian; but if he ever taught his doctrine there, he would be put out. The reason why angels rejoice is because they know that when a sinner repents, he is absolutely saved; or else they would rejoice prematurely, and would have good cause for retracting their merriment on some future occasion. But the angels know what Christ meant when he said, "I give unto my sheep eternal life, and they shall never perish, neither shall any pluck them out of my hand;" and therefore they rejoice over repenting sinners, because they know they are saved.

And I considered it a crime against humanity that I couldn't post it to christianity.se since I couldn't coax it into a christianity.se question (but then I realized I could make it into a meta.christianity.se question).

### Question

Is there some appropriate venue (perhaps a sister site) related to christianity.se (i.e. contains the people who are active on christianity.se), but focused on sharing interesting pieces of theology / sermons ?

It would basically be like pinterest (minus pictures + paragraphs of text) or twitter (up to 14k characters), with most of the users being christianity.se users.

Comment: Wow, Spurgeon had some serious misunderstandings about Arminian teaching, as well as the Bible's own teaching on the subject.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you've been learning, as part of the StackExchange network, Christianity.SE is a very focused site. Note, I did not say "community" there. The site itself tries not to focus on the social network in favor of sticking to good QnA.

There are lots of things that this site does *not do*. We don't try to cover all the basis. The SE philosophy is that better QnA can be achieved by cutting out the noise -- by not trying to be a forum or discussion site or social network or bobsled competition. **One of the biggest hurdles we have with people new to the site is convincing them that SE is only good for certain kinds of questions.**

That being said, there are extended parts of the network that have a role to play.

For starters, there our site [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1167/the-upper-room). In there, we don't really have rules about something being off topic. It's a place for anybody who happens to be hanging out to interact on a more personal level than questions and answers allows. Because the chat is permanently logged, there doesn't even have to be current participants for you to drop in and share something. If you found something you think C.SE users would like, drop a link in the chat room. There are a couple dozen people that drop by periodically. Content that users like might get stared and people that come by weeks later can still catch your link or salient comment. Sometimes special chat rooms even open up to cover specific topics.

Also, there is a [blog we call Eschewmenical](http://christianity.blogoverflow.com/). The authors are all contributors to this site. Topics are picked monthly and representatives with distinctly different perspectives cover the issue on behalf of a certain Christian tradition, particularly highlighting some of the differences. You can see several posts about that [here on meta](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blog) or even [chat about it](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2567). You could perhaps add something like "influential sermons" as a suggested future topic.

In summary, not everything related to Christianity will have a place on this site. When you do come across  questions that fit the format, please bring them!

P.S. One of the things we try to AVOID is pastoral advice questions. Pretty much across the board we agree that these should best be handled in the context of a local church. However much we disagree about what sort of church that should be, we agree that *this site is not the place for those*. One could easily combine this sentiment with the SE philosophy of not being a social network and note that there are some kinds of fellowship for which the church is the correct venue for. **If you find yourself wanting to make Christianity.SE your spiritual community, we respectfully submit you are in the wrong place.** Please fill the need for a local church first and use this site as an additional resource for asking questions that you might not have local expertise for, particularly traditions other than your own.

Comment: +1: I clearly misunderstood the goals of Christianity.SE -- Thanks for the clarifications.